# Crashlytics not sending events on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I've migrated our app from `react-native-firebase` to `@react-native-firebase/crashlytics` and managed to get crash reports from Android, but no luck with iOS.

I've done all the following:

- removed `react-native-fabric` and all of it's references
- installed `@react-native-firebase/app`
- installed `@react-native-firebase/crashlytics`
- added `GoogleServices-info.plist` in xCode as described in the manual
- added `firebase.json` in the root of the app with `crashlytics_debug_enabled: true` (this solved Android)

But still no success, not from the simulator nor from appCenter deployed app.

I think it's good to mention that we have 3 schemes (dev, staging, production).

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem!

Comment: nah, we postponed the upgrade and am now trying to tackle this again. will update once we succeed

Comment: @Lucky_girl I filed a support ticket to Firebase and their reply was that React-Native isn't supported and they recommended to look what we might have forgot to remove from react-native-fabric and to contact react-native-fabric support... guess we'll look for another crash log service ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah, I got pretty similar response from Firebase Support, quite disappointing...

Answer (score 0):

Chintan from Firebase. Can you reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) with the bundle ids of all 3 variant? You can also reference this SO post in there. It might just need manual activation.

Comment: filed a support ticket as suggested

Comment: Response was that React-native isn't supported and also added a suggestion what might cause this with the recommendation to contact react-native-fabric library maintainers... seems like we'll be looking for a different crash logging service

Comment: @Christian  I got pretty similar response from Firebase Support, quite disappointing...